# Chamar duas funções dentro de outra função no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu queria fzr uma tabuada e do lado duas opções, uma anterior e uma de próxima que seria adicionar e retirar o numero informado.(adicionei o css só pra ficar bonitinho), alguem saberia me dar uma dica de como eu faço isso?

```js
function Gerar() {
  const num = document.getElementById('num').value
  const tab = document.getElementById('tabuada')
  if (num.length == 0) {
    alert('[ERROR]Confira Todos os Campos')
  } else {
    const n = Number(num)
    tab.innerHTML = ''
    for (let c = 1; c <= 10; c++) {
      let item = document.createElement('option')
      item.text = `${n} x ${c} = ${n*c}`
      tab.appendChild(item)
    }

  }

}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(223, 239, 253);
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
}

#center {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.inv {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.vis {
  visibility: visible;
}

#gerar {
  width: 300px;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(248, 252, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<header>
  <h1>Tabuada</h1>
</header>


<body>
  <div id="center">
    <label for="num">Digite o Número ao lado:<input type="number" name="num" id="num"></label>
    <input type="button" value="Gerar" id="gerar" onclick="Gerar()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="ante" id="back" onclick="back()"> 
    <select name="tabuada" id="tabuada" size="10">
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="prox" id="next" onclick="next()">
  </div>
</body>


<footer>
  <p>&copy; pezinho</p>
</footer>


<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

E Uma outra dúvida que tenho(essa não precisa responder), é q no final do js eu adicionei a função abaixo e ele só adicionava +1 numero, exemplo: n = 1, eu clicava, n = 2, clicava de novo mas ele não adicionava +1, alguém poderia me explicar o pq?

```js
function next() {
    let num = document.getElementById('num').value
    let tab = document.getElementById('tabuada')
    var n = Number(num)
    n +=1
    tab.innerHTML = ''
    for (let c = 1; c <=10; c++) {
        let item = document.createElement('option')
        item.text = `${n} x ${c} = ${n*c}`
        tab.appendChild(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o erro do seu código acontece por que ao chamar as funções `back()` ou `next()`, você não atualiza o valor do `input.num`, calculando sempre o valor referente ao primeiro número inserido.

```
    function gerar() {
    const num = document.getElementById('num').value;

    if (num.length === 0 ) {
        alert('[ERROR]Confira Todos os Campos');
    } else {
        tabuada(num);
    }

}

function tabuada(num) {
    const tab = document.getElementById('tabuada');
    tab.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        let item = document.createElement('option');
        item.text = `${num} x ${i} = ${num * i}`;
        tab.appendChild(item);
    }
}  

function back() {
    const elementNumber = document.getElementById('num');
    const numberBack = Number(elementNumber.value) - 1;
    elementNumber.value = numberBack;
    tabuada(numberBack);
}

function next() {
    const elementNumber = document.getElementById('num');
    const numberNext = Number(elementNumber.value) + 1;
    elementNumber.value = numberNext;
    tabuada(numberNext);
}
```

Comment: cara, vc abriu mt minha mente, vlww